# QGIS maximum function returns too many records

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute

At 3.18.3, I am working with a standalone Geopackage attribute table containing data for a threatened bird species who are nesting in bird boxes.

The nesting boxes are periodically checked and the number of observed eggs are recorded.  The data table looks like this:

*box_id, observation_date, number_of_eggs:*

1, 2021-05-17, 1
1, 2021-06-13, 0
2, 2021-05-17, 0
3, 2021-05-17, 1
3, 2021-06-09, NULL
3, 2021-06-13, 3

For each *box_id* I need to select the one record that contains the greatest number of eggs ever observed.  Records with lesser, zero, or NULL egg values are to be ignored.  If a box never had any eggs, it is likewise ignored.

In other words, did a given nest box produce eggs, and if so, what was the greatest number of eggs ever observed?

Using ***maximum("number_of_eggs",group_by:= "box_id")*** within Select by Expression, this is what I desire and expect (selected records are bolded):

**1, 2021-05-17, 1**
1, 2021-06-13, 0
2, 2021-05-17, 0
3, 2021-05-17, 1
3, 2021-06-09, NULL
**3, 2021-06-13, 3**

But this is what I see:

**1, 2021-05-17, 1**
**1, 2021-06-13, 0**
2, 2021-05-17, 0
**3, 2021-05-17, 1**
**3, 2021-06-09, NULL**
**3, 2021-06-13, 3**

It appears that the function is selecting **all** records for a given *box_id*, if that *box_id* ever contained one or more eggs.

How can I modify the expression to select just the single record with the maximum number of eggs for each *box_id*?

Comment: Are you applying that filter expression to "number_of_eggs" or "box_id"?

Comment: @MBain you may be on to something.  But assuming that a filter expression would solve the problem, I do not know how to use the one associated with the *maximum* function. The accompanying statement says that *filter = optional expression to use to filter features used to calculate aggregate.* But what does that obtuse statement mean? I cannot find any instructions regarding how to use such a filter, or what it would look like...

Comment: I didn't mean the filter inside the aggregate function - I just meant the overall "Select by expression"/Advanced Filter.  I think the Advanced filter expression should be:  `"number_of_eggs" = maximum("number_of_eggs",group_by:= "box_id")`.  At the moment its looks to me like the filter is selecting any rows where the box_id happens to equal the maximum number of eggs, ie the filter is set to `"box_id" = maximum("number_of_eggs",group_by:= "box_id")` - thats why box 2 is not picked up by the filter 2 != 0

Comment: Oh gosh, you are correct, and I feel pretty stupid!  Thanks for your help, and please convert your comment to an answer so that I can credit you.  FWIW, to exclude the zero values, I modified the expression to this: "number_of_eggs" > 0 and "number_of_eggs" = maximum("number_of_eggs",group_by:= "box_id")

Comment: Heh! We've all been there. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the Advanced filter expression should be:
`"number_of_eggs" = maximum("number_of_eggs",group_by:= "box_id")`

At the moment its looks to me like the filter is selecting any rows where the box_id happens to equal the maximum number of eggs, ie the filter is set to `"box_id" = maximum("number_of_eggs",group_by:= "box_id")` - thats why box 2 is not picked up by the filter, 2 != 0